# Automation - Replace Connection Properties on Excel

Tags: excel, module, automation

I'm currently working on maintaining some old (new format .xlsx) excels with more than 60+ connections each that feed some various tables from a SqlServer.

I'm in search of some kind of toolkit, module, standalone script (or anything really) that let me **bulk change the command text inside each connection properties**.

The change should be not harder than changing part of the table name as the new table only contains the information that the table needs.

So far, the only thing that gets near what I need are those [python modules](http://www.python-excel.org/) but they don't appear to implement anything for handling connections.

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.